# React - Playing chunks of audio file in sequence - Decoding failure in Safari and FireFox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have a specific scenario that I have to send an audio in chunks from backend to the frontend through a socket connection and play the audio chunks in sequence.

Here is my React code:

```
function SampleComponent() {
  const socketInstanceRef = useRef<Socket | null>(null);
  const audioContextRef = useRef<AudioContext | null>(null);
  const audioChunkQueueRef = useRef<Buffer[]>([]);
  const isPlayingRef = useRef<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      audioContextRef.current = new window.AudioContext({
        latencyHint: "playback",
      });

      ...socket connection initialization

      socketInstanceRef.current.on("audio-chunks", async (chunk) => {
        audioChunkQueueRef.current.push(chunk);
        if (!isPlayingRef.current) {
          playNextChunk();
        }
      });

      const playNextChunk = async () => {
        isPlayingRef.current = true;
        const chunk = audioChunkQueueRef.current.shift();
        try {
          const audioBuffer = await audioContextRef.current!.decodeAudioData(
            chunk!
          );
          const source = audioContextRef.current!.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = audioBuffer;
          source.connect(audioContextRef.current!.destination);
          source.start();
          source.onended = () => {
            isPlayingRef.current = false;
            playNextChunk();
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
   <div>Example</div>
  );
}

export default SampleComponent;
```

It works perfectly in Chrome but it throws the following errors in Safari and FireFox:

> FireFox: DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.

> Safari: EncodingError: Decoding failed

The most strange part is that the very first chunk is being played successfully both in Safari and FireFox but the next chunks fail.

**What I have already tried:**

I have tried to change the format of the audio from mp3 to aac and flac in backend when emitting the chunks but It didn't solve the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: So here are some updates: 
After some research I found out that mp3 files have one header. So when we send this file in chunks, only the first chunk has the correct header that AudioContext can decode it (However, it is still unknown that how Chrome can decode it)